# Can arbitrary comparator be transformed into equivalent key for radix sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

When reading documentation for Rust crate [Voracious Sort](https://docs.rs/voracious_radix_sort/latest/voracious_radix_sort/) I noticed how much faster it is than the comparison-based algorithm (PDQ) provided by Rust standard library, with both stable and in-place versions available.

Why aren't we using radix for everything? Of course, radix sorts can only be applied to integral types.

However, most other types of data can be (more or less easily) transformed into integral types (common examples are IEEE754 floats or strings). My question thus is:

**What types of data are required (or are significantly faster) to be sorted with comparisons, and why?**

Or, even more generally:

**Is it possible for any** (deterministic?) **comparator of keys to be transformed into** (finite?) **radix-sortable key mapping function?**

It seems like it should be a simple proof, but I can't quite put it together.

*I do understand that other algorithms are better for some distributions of input data. I'm asking about types of data, not their distributions.*

Comment: How do you convert a long string to an integral type?  And how do you maintain the ordering when you do so?

Comment: @Mark Ransom Convert each character to a number that defines it's order (e.g. for ascii it is already done, we sort by their literal codes), then use the string array as n-byte integer, where n is the length of the longest string, padded with zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* actually use Radix sort for pretty much any kind of keys.

The problem is how to write the *interface* for a *generic* sorting function.

To use a generic comparison-based sorting function, you just need to provide a comparator that can tell you whether one key is greater than or less than another.

To use a generic radx-sort function, you would need to implement a *view* of the keys that presents them to the sort function as a sequence of digits.  For all but the simplest kinds of keys that can be pretty difficult, and not very efficient.  It's not the kind of thing you want to do just to call a sort function, and so there's not enough demand for a generic radix-sort to have it included in standard libraries.

Comment: I'd assume most types can have their "views" implemented by the standard library the same way comparators are implemented for most types. Can you give an example of type where it would not be easy to chain these provided views in a similar fashion to comparator chaining?

Comment: Or, ideally (if you have time) can you please provide concrete examples for both of your points?

Comment: See https://probablydance.com/2016/12/27/i-wrote-a-faster-sorting-algorithm/

Comment: @KryštofVosyka A concrete example of a poor implementation wouldn't prove that there aren't any good ones, but I suggest you try it for yourself -- make a class that provides a string-like view of a (string,date) pair that works for all strings and dates and would often support a radix sort that was faster than `.sort()` with a comparator.  If you succeed, the task will have been too difficult to justify the advantage.

Comment: @MattTimmermans The only complex part is that each key doesn't know the common largest string length, and thus cannot pad it's own string properly, however to me it seems like such complexity can be offloaded to the sorting function. You can just provide a tuple of (string, date) and the sorting function should take care to properly pad the array types (string). (and dates easily transform into an integer type)

Answer (score -2):

> In terms of data types, Radix sort is like sorting your music playlist by the song duration (which is a number). But what if you want to sort by the song title? Transforming song titles into numbers (like how 'A' is 65 in ASCII) can be a lot of work. If two songs have the same duration, a stable sort keeps them in the original order. Not all ways of doing radix sort guarantee this. Imagine sorting books on a shelf (comparison sort) versus taking them all off, putting them into piles by the first letter in the title, then by the second letter, and so on (radix sort). The latter needs more space (for the piles).
> So, while radix sort is superfast for some things (like numbers), it's not always the best tool for the job. It's like using a hammer for a nail - great! But for a screw? Not so much. You pick the tool that works best for your task.

Comment: This is not true. Benchmarks show that radix sort can be a lot faster for strings, especially for long strings with long common prefixes. Transforming strings into numbers is usually not a lot of work (e.g. for ascii the underlining representation IS the numbers), in case of Unicode, it's just a table lookup. Stable and in-place radix sorts also exist. Only time when radix sort is slow is when the number of elements is low (<1000), however in those cases usual algorithms often also behave poorly and are outclassed by like insertion sort.